javascript show kb left of a download
is it possible to show the user via javascript how much is left (in kb) to fully download a gif file from a remote server?
    function downgif(id, img){
    //show downloading
    Show('downloadgif');
    
    //chenge img
    document.getElementById(id).src=img;
   
   //test if complete
    var completeInterval = null, renderedInterval = null, count = 0;
    var theImg = document.getElementById(id);
    theImg.src = img;
    // Wait for image to be loaded (but not necessarily rendered)
    completeInterval = setInterval(function() {
      if (theImg.complete) {
        // Cancel checking once IMG is loaded OR we've tried for ~9s already
        clearInterval(completeInterval);
        completeInterval = null;
          // IMG is now 'complete' - but that just means it's in the render queue...
          // Wait for naturalWidth and naturalHeight to be > 0 since this shows
          // that the image is done being RENDERED (not just 'loaded/complete')
          renderedInterval = setInterval(function() {
            if (theImg.naturalHeight > 0 && theImg.naturalWidth > 0) {
              clearInterval(renderedInterval);
              renderedInterval = null;

              //hide downliading
              Hide('downloadgif');
            }
          }, 100);
      }
    }, 450);
 
}


Yes, it's possible to display how much is left to fully download a GIF file from a remote server, but it requires using the XMLHttpRequest or Fetch API to track download progress (rather than a <img />)
XMLHttpRequest
XMLHttpRequest provides a onprogress event which can be used to calculate the progress of a download.


function downgif(url, imgElementId) {
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    const imgElement = document.getElementById(imgElementId);

    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    xhr.onprogress = function(event) {
          const kbRemaining = ((event.total - event.loaded) / 1024).toFixed(2);
          console.log(`Remaining: ${kbRemaining} KB`);
    };

    xhr.onload = function() {
          const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
          imgElement.src = blobUrl;
          console.log("Download complete.");
    };

    xhr.send();
}

const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/-WikiForHumanRights2022Right_to_a_healthy_environment._%281%29_%281%29.gif";
downgif(url, 'gifDisplay');
<img id="gifDisplay">



Fetch
fetch allows you to download the response as a stream, which can also have it's progress calculated from the Content-Length header.


async function downgif(url, imgElementId) {
    const imgElement = document.getElementById(imgElementId);
    const response = await fetch(url);
    
    const contentLength = response.headers.get('Content-Length');
    
    const total = parseInt(contentLength, 10);
    let loaded = 0;

    const reader = response.body.getReader();
    const chunks = [];
    while (true) {
        const { done, value } = await reader.read();
        if (done) break;

        chunks.push(value);
        loaded += value.length;

        const kbRemaining = ((total - loaded) / 1024).toFixed(2);

        console.log(`Remaining: ${kbRemaining} KB`);
    }


    const blob = new Blob(chunks);
    const blobUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    imgElement.src = blobUrl;

    console.log("Download complete.");
}

const url = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/31/-WikiForHumanRights2022Right_to_a_healthy_environment._%281%29_%281%29.gif";
downgif(url, 'gifDisplay');
<img id="gifDisplay">



If you want to test this on other large GIFs, Wikipedia provides many examples (which is where the demo GIF I used came from)

Thanks a lot... just a problem... mine download the image, yours (both) says: Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://...............gif. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200.

Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors
